# Porting into Laravel: Migration from raw SQL Dumps

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, database-migration, laravel-5.6

In my project, I am moving from Codeigniter into Laravel, also I am starting to use phpunit tests as well. In this project there are many legacy databases without any sort of migrations. From them I want to autogenerate a test databases for integration testing.

But there's a thorn in my idea: 
How to autogenerate an existing test database and nuke it if requested? There are no database migrations in the existing project so I need to create them in the newly-generated project.

So far I generated a dump of my database using `pg-dump` (I use a postgresql flavor as my database). The dump is an sql file. I also created an initial migration using the command:

```
php ./artisan make:migration --path ./database/migrations/myDb InitialDb
```

That generated the following code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class InitialDb extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //Read and execute the sql dump.
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //Delete anything except the test data.
    }
}
```

So I want to know how I can execute the sql code generated from the in the generated dump?

Answer (score 1):

There are some generator packages you can get which will read through the database and generate the migrations you need. We've done this in the past when converting to laravel from another framework. This wasn't from a dump file, but rather the raw database itself but I hope it helps anyway!

https://www.5balloons.info/create-migration-files-from-existing-database-in-laravel/

Comment: Is this solution able to handle stuff such as foreighn database wrappers and foreighn tables?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm honest, I've never had to try! If you find it does though or a similar package that does the job  I'd be interested to know

Comment: Even though looks for foreign tables it does not generate them correctly, it generates them as normal ones for postgresql.